# Ionic 2 Google Sign-in - retrieve gender and birthday

Tags: angular, google-api, oauth-2.0, ionic2, google-signin

I am trying to build an Ionic 2 App with google sign in and I need to retrieve the persons gender and birthday.

This is my code so far:

```
doGoogleLogin() {
    GooglePlus.login(
      {
        'scopes': 'profile',
        'webClientId': 'myClientId'
      }
    )
    .then(userData => {
      let token = userData.idToken;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(userData);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

The userData only contains an idToken, email and name of the user.
Ionics [Google Plus Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus/) does not provide a function for calling any other API endpoint. I already tried to get an oauth access token from `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth` and use the Google People API with https calls but I could not make it work.

Any help will be appreciated!

These sources may also be helpful: [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing#AboutAuthorization), [OAuth 2.0 for Mobile Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp)

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @Shabeer is only partially true. For public profile attributes (like gender), you can use your application key to retrieve the information. For private profile data attributes (like birthday), it is mandatory to use an OAuth 2.0 token, that is, the user must login with some specific scopes that generate an OAuth accept token that allows you to retrieve the private attribute.

Please, read carefully [Google People Authorise Request](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing) page. Once you have the access token, you can get the information using two APIs. First one is Google+, using the URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me

Adding the header `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>` to the request.

To test this approach, use [Google+ people get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get). Note that the permissions used in this API (click on `show scopes`) are slightly different from the Google People API (second option). The permissions are:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

At the time of writing this post and for the time being, I haven't had success using directly the second option, [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get), to get age range, but birthday is available. Use previous URL to test the query,  and note that permissions are different from Google+ API (click on `show scopes`).

Use Chrome Developer Tools or any other browser console to see network requests and OAuth tokens used by test pages. You can test your queries using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com).

Hope this helps you,
Xavi

Answer (score -1):

Working api path...

You can  make get api call using below api path, which will return only public gender and public birthday..

Requirements: 
1. Make sure u have the userId of the user who gets logged in.You will get the userId from the login response.
2. And you need the api key which u will get from google developer console at the credential section ...Just follow the below link and at the credentials section u will get the api key.

[**Google Developer console**](https://console.developers.google.com/)

And finally make the GET Api call using below Api path....

"https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/"  + **userId** + "?key=" + **apiKey**

Note: Make sure u replace the userId and apiKey using requirements step 1 and 2.

Comment: this API doesn't respond gender and birthday. i have tried and this is the response
 {
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\"RKS4-q7QGL10FxltAebpjqjKQR0/gKLm8Bbvy8oUmF7r6KCkt-c_wJQ\"",
 "objectType": "person",
 "id": "104137425014601830191",
 "displayName": "Tester Ucodice",
 "name": {
  "familyName": "Ucodice",
  "givenName": "Tester"
 },
 "url": "https://plus.google.com/104137425014601830191",
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/xxxxxxxxx",
  "isDefault": true
 },
 "isPlusUser": true,
 "circledByCount": 0,
 "verified": false
}